# Uncountable or countable infinite set when a die is rolled infinite times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Say if a die were to be rolled an infinite amount of times this will result in an infinite amount of outcomes. However I believe that the resulting set will be an uncountable set even though if we were to roll the die an infinite amount of times. My reasoning is because we can not establish a one to one correspondence (hence not making it bijection) between the rolls and be able to count them individually.

Comment: I am a little unclear … What is this ‘resulting set’ defined as?

Comment: Your “reasoning” is a conclusion, not a proof.  How do you *know* that there is no such correspondence?  It’s not good enough to say merely that you can’t think of one because that leaves open the possibility that you simply haven’t thought of the right correspondence.

Comment: You have to actually prove the uncountability, Cantor's diagonal argument is what you nedd. This works  even for two outcomes (say heads or tails with infinite coin tosses).

Comment: You mean the set of possible outcomes because rolling a die (even infinite many often) leads to a single sequence of digits.

Answer (score 1):

The set of outcomes of the experiment is, presumably, $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. This is known to be an uncountable set (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).